# Make PostgreSQL DB copy with qt tools

Tags: sql, postgresql, qt

Is it possible to make a copy of database using qt? For example I’m connected to some db and want to save a copy of this db as copy.sql file in a some folder and then maybe save it on cd or somewhere else.

Comment: What makes this question specific to Qt .. it seems an sql question?

Answer (score 0):

The only good way to make an SQL export of a PostgreSQL database is to use `pg_dump`. So you should call that executable from your application.

Be warned though that such a dump is only guaranteed to work when restored to a database of the same major version.